# Runlevel difference between login and logout?

Tags: lubuntu, runlevel

Using Lubuntu 12.04 I want to set a script to run every time I am at the login screen, but I cannot find any information about its run level.

Is it at a different run level by default? Can I make it a different one?

Comment: Lubuntu. is Lubuntu 12.04 not a LTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ubuntu Bootup Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) may be of service to you. To find out what runlevel you're at, just use the [`runlevel`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/runlevel.8.html) command. The `README` files in `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc[0-6].d` may also be useful.